# How to produce a CR/LF in linux text docs?

Tags: ascii

How do you produce a CR/LF anywhere in a text document created in linux OS so that it can be copied and pasted into a windows text editor or onto the web and retain the CR/LF to be read and acted upon in a windows OS or on the web? A for instance would be ascii art that requires CR/LF to keep character alignment accurate. Producing ascii art in linux with CR/LF codes that can be utilized in windows or online.

Comment: Copy/pasted how? Text document in *what context*? Are you talking about an interactive editor or are you...well... what *are* you talking about?

Comment: edited for clarity ( I hope )

Answer (score 6):

Don't worry about it, use standard `Unix/(GNU) Linux` tools, and then run
`unix2dos` on your Unix file.

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be done with `vim`.

If you want to convert all line breaks into CR/LFs in a file,

1. Open the file in vim (`vim file.txt`).
2. Convert the file to DOS format (which means CR/LF line breaks): `:e ++ff=dos`.
3. Save and quit (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or `:wq`).

If you simply want to insert a single CR/LF line break,

1. Open the file in vim (`vim file.txt`).
2. Navigate to the line that you want to insert a CR/LF line break after (if you're not familiar with vim, you can just use the up and down arrow keys).
3. Enter insert mode, appending to the end of the line (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).
4. Insert a carriage return character (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>).
5. Insert a line feed character (<kbd>Return</kbd>).
6. Exit insert mode (<kbd>Esc</kbd>).
7. Save and quit (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or `:wq`).

Comment: ok for clarification (my fault) I am using linux simple text editor and want the CR and the LF to be stored so that when pasted into a MS text editor or into a web chat the CR and LF are acted upon and transferred to the receiving  environment.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** So what you actually want to know is **how to convert a file from Unix to Windows line endings.** Do it from the command line, not the editor, with the following one-liner. It will work correctly even if you run it on the same file multiple times.

```
perl -pe 's/\r?\n/\r\n/' unix-file.txt > windows-file.txt
```

You can view a file with `od -c` to see its newline characters.

PS. By the way some editors will let you save in DOS format and/or preserve the existing line endings (but who knows what you're using.)

---

Here's the answer for what you *thought* you wanted:

If you really want to enter them explicitly, you need to know two things: The control codes for CR and LF, and how your editor or whatever lets you enter literal control codes.

1. CR is `^M` (<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>). LF is `^L` (<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>).
2. Find out how your editor "escapes" the next thing you'll type. In emacs that's <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (`^Q`, or `C-q` in emacs notation), so you'd type `^Q ^M` to enter a CR. A more common escape (e.g. in vim and on the bash prompt) is `^V`.

Note also that LF is the end of line, so you'll probably not see it after it's entered. But it's there.

Answer (score 0):

you could try [Geany](http://www.geany.org/), it's a gui type text editor, and line endings are one of the many things you can edit.